# Is there anyway to close a page

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new at this wpf page navigation. I always using : `Main.Content = new History_page();`
I mean I always creating a new page but everytime I open a new one this program uses a little bit ram if you are physico enough you can overload the system. Is there anyway to show always same page to user and prevent something like that

Comment: "you can overload the system" - nope. GC watches.

Comment: The point is, that the garbage collection is taking care of the pages not referenced to anymore. And what you see is an increase in the memory use before the garbage collection is cleaning up, so don't worry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of `History_page` each time you want to navigate to it, you could create one cached instance that you reuse in a field:

```
private static readonly _cachedPage = new History_page();
...
Main.Content = _cachedPage;
```